# Number of non-intersecting paths for two bodies on a Cartesian grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coordinate-systems

Each body is allowed a jump of $+1 \uparrow$ or $+1 \rightarrow$ in one step. There are $n$ steps available to each body. Find the number of non-intersecting path pairs between a fixed source and a fixed destination within this grid.

Assume final destination is $X,Y$ and of course, $X + Y = n$.

**My approach**

Let $\Delta X_1, \Delta Y_1$ and $\Delta X_2, \Delta Y_2$ be the displacement vectors for body 1 and body 2 respectively.

Let $Array(\Delta X_1)$ denote the array containing the values of $\Delta X_1$ indexed by step, and so on for other vectors too. Note that there is a bijection between $Array(\Delta X_1)$ and $Array(\Delta Y_1)$, because a body can jump only along one axis at a time.

So we have to consider only $Array(\Delta X_1)$ and $Array(\Delta X_2)$ to find the number of paths. The paths intersect if at any particular step, $\Delta X_1 = \Delta X_2$, which also implies $\Delta Y_1 = \Delta Y_2$ from the bijection (so ideally, this should happen only at the source and the destination). $Array(\Delta X_1)$ is $n$ sized and monotonic increasing over its length and $Set(Array(\Delta X_1))$ is $\mathbb{N}_{\leq X}$.

An example of a pair of non-intersecting paths for source $(0,0)$ and destination $(4,4)$ is-

**Body 1** - $Array(\Delta X_1) = \{ 0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4\}$ and $Array(\Delta Y_1) = \{ 1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4\}$

**Body 2** - $Array(\Delta X_2) = \{ 1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4\}$ and $Array(\Delta Y_2) = \{ 0,1,1,1,2,2,3,4\}$

This scenario can be condensed to a series of $\rightarrow$ and $0$ (we need to consider only one of the $x$ and $y$ displacement vectors, as the latter can be derived uniquely from the former). If the displacement is $+1$, place a $\rightarrow$ on the final coordinate, else $0$.

So - **Body 1** - $Array(\Delta X_1) = \{ 0,0,0,\rightarrow,0,\rightarrow,\rightarrow,\rightarrow\}$ and **Body 2** - $Array(\Delta X_2) = \{ \rightarrow,0,\rightarrow,\rightarrow,0,\rightarrow,0,0\}$.

So basically find the number of pairs of such binary strings where the initial substring of **Body 1** $Array(\Delta X_1)$ always has lesser $\rightarrow$ than its counterpart's corresponding inital substring.

Is there a better approach? Hints please.

Comment: See OEIS: [A000891](https://oeis.org/A000891)

Comment: Check  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma

Comment: @DanielMathias how does that help, apart from being a link to the answer for a very specific case? Please elaborate wrt the my question.

Comment: @Phicar I am in want of a more elegant solution

Comment: @shadyshamus More elegant than using this amazing result? The idea of involution is one of the most elegant ideas in enumerative combinatorics.

Comment: @Phicar , just on a side note, will my approach lead anywhere? Do you have something in that vein?

Comment: Most likely, you will end up thinking in eliminate overlapping by flipping paths around intersections. So far you have defined necessary ideas, but I do not see any "approach". My suggestion is you read carefully the proof of this lemma and see that the idea is very natural.

Comment: Do you mean $X=Y=n$ in the third line? Do you aim for a formula, or a computation strategy?

Comment: I am so sorry @Sudix ; $n$ is the total number of steps. Although the expected result is a formula, I can do with the strategy too. I suggest you write the formula too for the benefit of future viewers.

Comment: One way to obtain a recursion for the problem is to move to the complementary problem of finding number of paths of two objects on an $n\times n $ grid with at least one intersection. This number you can calculate by calculating the number of paths of two objects on an $n\times n$ grid which have its first intersection at $(a,b)$. And for that object you then can give a recursion. However, the recursion isn't really clean (it's a double summation), so I doubt you can wrap it up into a closed formula